# Why did the T-101 model allow Sarah Connor to terminate it?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

At the end of T2: Judgement day, when Sarah Connor lowers the T-101 into the molten steel; how is that that the T-101 just allows her to do this? Would that not be forcing itself to self-terminate?

It's understandable that the T-101 could not just jump into the molten steel because that would be self-terminating. But isn't allowing someone to help in the assistance of self-terminating the same thing?

Calculations that had to have been going through its head. "Well, I am allowing Sarah Connor to help me self-terminate. Override. I am allowing her to...override." Etc.

Comment: Computer logic being rather specific, "don't harm yourself" is different to "don't allow yourself to be harmed by others"

Comment: Funny thing is, I found that through the entire movie, the T-101 never selected only John Connor to listen to or did it? If John ordered it NOT to go, it technically should have stayed. Also, Sarah Connor was the individual who helped him self-terminate. Why would it still allow someone else, knowing that John Connor was not the one, to help lower him into the steel? Crazy right?

Comment: I think the idea was that thanks to having his learning ability turned on he was developing a degree of free will, allowing him to act beyond his programming, at least to some extent.

Comment: Hw wouldn't get into robot Heaven.

Comment: Joe L. And we all know what would happen if it became self aware. Bad terminator. Dum dum DUMMMMMM!

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - My take is that by the end it's developed sufficiently to prioritise keeping John safe, by destroying itself, over following his orders. Earlier in the film (or had they not put the CPU into read/write mode) the Terminator would have just followed his orders blindly.

Comment: Did you only just see this movie?

Comment: @Sonny Ordell: No I just keep coming across it when I look through the tv guide. Always trying to figure out "why".

I was always a huge fan of the Terminator series, especially with this movie, the first time I had seen it when I was 10.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar Same here (being a huge fan at least), just noticed a lot of recent questions so was curious. The bigger problem for me was that the T-800 left an arm behind before going into the lava, when the arm left behind from the first movie created all sorts of problems.

Comment: @Sonny Ordell: Good thing to ask a question about before I "steel" (bad pun?) it ;).

Yeah. For me, I am a bit slow. It usually takes me watching a movie multiple times before actually seeing details I would want to ask questions about.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar Someone already did :) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15184/why-was-the-t800s-arm-in-t2-overlooked

Comment: @Sonny Ordell: So I ended up going to that question and my only take on it was that James Cameron might have been using it as the fourth wall? Am I even using that term right? In case he wanted to expand on the franchise. It would be a good excuse to have T-3 right? And thus, the reason why Judgement Day might have been postponed.

Comment: T3 didn't even acknowledge it. And Fourth wall means communicating directly with the audience. I think the easiest explanation is it just got lost/thrown out, since it would have been garbled and people wouldn't have understood it to be something of value.

Comment: @Sonny Ordell: No I meant that it was implied due to there being another movie. In the T-3, the T-800 says that Judgement Day was not stopped, but postponed. If someone found that arm, just like the one Dyson had throughout T-2; it could still could have kept the conclusion open ended, due to the audience having no idea as to whether it was thrown out or not.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar Nope it's unrelated. The point of T3 was to try and show the future can't be stopped (in contrast to the point of T2). Skynet in T3 comes from a military project, purely software based. No link to the arm or Cyberdyne what so ever.

Answer (score 4):

The Terminator was initially programmed to follow John Connor's orders with the explicit remit of keeping John safe from harm ("*My mission is to protect you*") unless ordered otherwise (*“You have to do what I say?” “That is one of the mission parameters.”*).

When John placed the Terminator's CPU into [read/write mode](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x615wr_terminator-2-judgment-day-cpu-reset_shortfilms), he created a situation where the machine was able to start thinking for itself and becoming self-aware, something that Skynet was evidently against.

By the end, it's clear from both the script and screenplay that the Terminator has begun to exceed its initial programming. It has gained an *awareness* of human emotion (and in the novelisation begun to have outright feelings) and has realised that its continued existence puts John at greater threat. On top of that, it openly ignores its own primary directive by disobeying a direct order from John not to allow itself to be destroyed.

It appears that the proscription from self-termination is hardwired into the Terminator in a way that can't be immediately overwritten but that there's nothing to stop it from *allowing itself* to be terminated, especially given that doing so will enable it to keep John safe.

Note that in each of the novelisation, the original screenplay and [the finalised shooting script](http://www.terminatorfiles.com/media/scripts/), the terminator *does* self-terminate, throwing itself into the molten steel. The line about not being able to kill itself (and the scene where the Terminator is lowered into the steel) seem to have been inserted later on.

**Script**

> **SARAH :** *Are you afraid?*
>
> **TERMINATOR :** *Yes.*
>
> **He turns and steps off the edge.** They watch him sink into the lava. He
>   disappears... the metal hand sinking last... at the last second it
>   forms into a fist with the thumb extended... a final thumbs up. Then
>   it is gone. <sub><sup>[Terminator Shooting Script Rev.
>   2](http://www.terminatorfiles.com/media/scripts/)</sup></sub>

**Frakes Novel**

> “No. There was another chip.”
>   He touched a metal finger to the side of his head.
>   Terminator looked at Sarah. They both knew what must be done.
>   John’s eyes went wide as he suddenly understood what he meant. He shook his head as his eyes began to fill with tears.
>   “No!”
>
> Terminator faced John. A hideous visage, with all the punishment it
>   had taken, but somehow noble ...kind.
>
> The man/machine said, “I have to go away, John.
>   It must end here ... or I am the future.” It turned a little so that
>   the battered human side of his face was in shadow. John saw the chrome
>   skull and the red eye.
>
> Still, John pleaded, “Don’t do it. Please ... it’ll be okay. Stay with
>   us—”
>
> Terminator put his hand on John’s shoulder. “I must complete my
>   mission.” And as he said that, the human side of his face came back
>   into the light. He reached toward John and his metal finger touched
>   the tear trickling down his cheek.
>
> It was the revelation.
>
> “I know now why you cry, although it is something I can never do.”
>
> He turned to Sarah and said, “Good-bye.”
>
> “Are you afraid?”
>
> There was the briefest instant before he responded.
>
> “Yes,” he said. Not because he was going to cease functioning as a
>   terminator, but because he had sensed a vision beyond his programming
>   of a cosmic order vast beyond even Skynet’s comprehension. And it gave
>   him the sense of his first feeling.
>
> Fear.
>
> Of where he was going next, if anywhere.
>
> Of course, he hadn’t been asked for further details on his answer, so
>   he didn’t say any of this. **He simply turned and stepped off the edge.**
>
> As Terminator fell, time stretched, and a flash of light engulfed his
>   mind. He was floating down a tunnel, following the flash of light into
>   something like oblivion.
>
> Or salvation.
>
> The artificial brain was seared when the chassis hit the molten steel.
>   Almost all electrical activity was stopped.

Comment: This is a very good answer. The other answer did add in that it may have been for a more dramatic effect to get the audience into feeling for the machine, like John did. Anywho, thanks!

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - I'm assuming test audiences wanted him to die in a more dramatic fashion. Suicide (even of a machine) isn't the most fun to watch.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a fairly simple matter for it - somewhere in its programming was obviously a very cardinal instruction not to 'self terminate'.  Asimov explains his own version of this same law by tying it to the very valuable and expensive piece of equipment that a robot represents - the investment its owners have made.  Skynet probably thought along the same lines.

However Connor had reprogrammed the model to obey his commands and more importantly to remove itself from the time line assuming its mission was successful.  Therefore - the expected, lethal resistance to being terminated by a third party was removed, but not the underlying and very deeply buried rule not to self-terminate in the first place...  The desire for self-preservation is supposedly similarly deeply-ingrained inhuman psychology.  You could perhaps explain it in narrative terms as having something to do with the limited time Connor had to reprogramme an obsolete model he just happened to have on hand to frustrate the T1000 he already knew had been sent back to murder him.  Maybe he could only strip away the logic that made it obey skynet - or perhaps he could just swap the existing compulsion to obey skynet's commands to one that obeyed his own...  Really though it was a weak point in the script - or a cynical one.  Cameron knew it would be a really good tear-jerker to end on, but maybe the idea of suicide was not so rosy.  Therefore a heroic sacrifice - from a machine - for the good of humanity.

Comment: Good answer. I would have thought along the same lines as well.